# sencha package fails to run zipalign in release mode

Tags: android, build, sencha-touch, extjs

I am trying to package my sencha application to android and I am using senchaCommandv3 and sencha-touch2.1rc2 library.

in the command prompt for debug configuration
sencha package build packager.json 
this command executes without anyerror and successfully generates .apk file.

but when i try to generate package in release mode it fails and gives error that "could not zipalign with error1"

please help, i am stucked pretty badly at this error. can;t find anything on this error.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use Phonegap it is a comparatively painless process. But if you want to use Sencha Native pacakger then upgrade to touch 2.1 GA release also ensure you have Sencha CMD build version 250 and try again.The earliers versions had some bugs which were documented in the Sencha Forums.

Hope this helps